# How to disable material3 theme for specific components in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, material3

I have a custom theme with material3 set to true.

```
static ThemeData light(context) => ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
```

I do not like the current implementation of the Chip component and I would like to use the previous material2 implementation.

How to configure the ThemeData to customize of Chip widgets of my app without wrapping all Chips with a Theme widget

```
Theme(
                data: ThemeData(useMaterial3: false),
                child: ChoiceChip(...)
```

)

Answer (score 8):

You have probably already found this answer, but I will answer it anyway, and it is useful for people who did not find this requirement obvious (like me).

Just wrap the widget you want to deactivate **Material3** inside the Widget `Theme`, In this example I will apply it to the ***Switch*** Widget:

Create a Widget that returns a Chip and wrap it in the Widget Theme.

With ***Material3*** in `True`:

```
Theme(
  data: ThemeData(
    useMaterial3: true
  ),
  child: Switch(
    value: value,
    onChanged: (newValue) {
      onChange(newValue);
    }
  ),
)
```

[Switch with Material3 Theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9Dzu.png)

With Material3 in False:

```
Theme(
  data: ThemeData(
    useMaterial3: false
  ),
  child: Switch(
    value: value,
    onChanged: (newValue) {
      onChange(newValue);
    }
  ),
)
```

[Switch without Material3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAqqL.png)